# Invalid syntax error in newly installed python package pmock

Tags: python, pmock

I was installing [gump3](http://wiki.apache.org/gump/Gump3Installation) on my machine (Ubuntu 12.04 64bit). [pmock](http://pmock.sourceforge.net/) is one of the dependency.

I installed `pmock` successfully using following command:

```
sudo pip install pmock --allow-external pmock --allow-unverified pmock
```

However, when I try to import `pmock`, I get following error:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2015, 19:33:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pmock
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pmock.py", line 313
    def with(self, *arg_constraints, **kwarg_constraints):
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

This is the code in `pmock.py`:

```
def with(self, *arg_constraints, **kwarg_constraints):
       """Fully specify the method's arguments."""
       self._mocker.add_matcher(AllArgumentsMatcher(arg_constraints,
                                                  kwarg_constraints))
       return self
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [pmock page you linked in your question](http://pmock.sourceforge.net/) states:

> pMock has not been under active development since mid 2004.

and

> pMock is currently written for versions of Python >= 2.3

With Python 2.5, [the `with` statement (PEP 343)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), and with it, the `with` keyword was introduced. In Python 2.5, they'd only act as keyword when this new feature was explicitly turned on with

```
from __future__ import with_statement
```

but using `with` or `as` as identifiers (e.g. as a function name, as `pmock.py` does) would have caused a warning, even if the feature wasn't turned on.

Since Python 2.6, the feature is always turned on and it is an error to use `with` or `as` as identifiers. (See section **Transition Plan** of PEP 343.)

You are using Python 2.7.3 which is incompatible with pmock.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there any way to make this work? I mean, can I compile this code, using python 2.5 (with `with` feature turned off)? I intend to use python 2.7.3 for all other uses.

Comment: I have no idea. If you must use gump, it's probably easiest to install Python 2.4

Comment: @mohit you could change all usages of `with` to `with_` or something similar in that package

Comment: Ah, right, if the usage of `with` as identifier is the _only_ incompatibility, you can of course modify pmock source code. But if there are other Python-2.4-isms in it, that might become a hairy endeavor.